# How to use VLOOKUP() with a dynamic range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get email adress from another Excel (let's call it EmployeesFile) file matching the same user id in EmployeesFile and in the file I am working with.

In the below code, this what I am trying to do.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub getData()
    Dim pathKeys, pathEmployees As String
    pathKeys = openKeys
    pathEmployees = openEmployees
   
    If pathKeys <> "" Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Dim wbKeys As Workbook
        Set wbKeys = GetObject(pathKeys)
        wbKeys.Worksheets(1).Columns(2).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns(1)
        wbKeys.Worksheets(1).Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns(2)
        wbKeys.Worksheets(1).Columns(17).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns(3)
        wbKeys.Worksheets(1).Columns(19).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns(4)
        wbKeys.Worksheets(1).Columns(24).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns(5)
        wbKeys.Worksheets(1).Columns(25).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns(6)
        wbKeys.Worksheets(1).Columns(26).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns(7)
    End If
    
    
    If pathEmployees <> "" Then
        Dim wbEmployees As Workbook
        Dim cpt As Integer
        cpt = 1
        Set wbEmployees = GetObject(pathEmployees)
        Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
            Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns(8) = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],wbEmployees.worksheets(1).columns("A1:G"&cpt),6)"
            cpt = cpt + 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Loop
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I also use 2 `public function` to open differents files, here the code :

```vb
Public Function openKeys() As String
    Dim dialogBoxKeys As FileDialog
    Set dialogBoxKeys = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    MsgBox ("Sélectionnez le fichier Keys")
    With dialogBoxKeys
        .Title = "Keys File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            openKeys = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function openEmployees() As String
    Dim dialogBoxEmployees As FileDialog
    Set dialogBoxEmployees = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    MsgBox ("Sélectionnez le fichier Employees")
    With dialogBoxEmployees
        .Title = "Employees File"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = "C:\"
        If .Show = -1 Then
            openEmployees = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

I try to use `cpt` as a counter to loop every cells of email columns.
In a static way `Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1).columns(8)= "=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'Employees_2021-12-27_13_45_36_utf-8.csv'!R2C1:R3332C7,6)"` works perfectly.

However some vairables can change, as the range of the matrix and the name of the file.
To get the name and path of the file, I don't have any troubles to do that.

Is there a way to use variables instead of static path + static range ?

I want to learn from this, so, if possible, explain to me what I'm doing wrong here, or if my approach is lacking insight.

Comment: What `openKeys` is? `wbEmployees` has not been set and it must be separated by `&` from the rest of the formula string. Is it the whole code you use, or only part of it?

Comment: Yes sorry i did not show the whole code. `openKeys` is a public function  that returns path file as a string.

Comment: `wbEmployees` is set as `Set wbEmployees = GetObject(pathEmployees)`. This is equivalent to  `Set wbEmployees = Workbooks.Open(pathEmployees)` but in a faster way.

Comment: Why "in a faster way"? Then, all the `Vlookup` range can be returned for all involved range, at once in an array. Also the previous columns copying can be optimized, if the clipboard is avoided...

Comment: I read it allows to get data file without opening it. Yes all the columns copied can be done in better way, but I don't know yet how to optimized that. I am learning vba with this macro actually. I don't understand what you mean when you say I should use an array with `VLOOKUP()`

Comment: I do not think that you can `Set` a workbook without opening it. It should be good to also post the function in discussion. Please, try the code I posted. It assumes that the returned workbook objects are valid. I will stay in my office no more than 10 minutes. If something wrong with the code I posted, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications, mentioning the error, or what it does wrong against you need.

Comment: Otherwise, I will be able to reply only after some hours, when I will be at home...

Comment: Well it works nice to get data from `Keys File` when `Set wbKeys = GetObject(pathKeys)` and then use it for all `.Copy`.

Comment: And didn't it return the Vlookup array in column H:H?

Comment: I am going to edit my above code to show you `openKeys() ` and `openEmployees()`.

Comment: Until that, please insert the next testing line after `Set rngLV = ...`: Debug.Print rng.Address, rngLV.Address: Stop`. What does it return in `Immediate Window` when the code stops here? If OK, press `F5` to make code to continue.

Comment: The used functions only let you choose the workbooks to be used. If you know their full path, it is faster to place it in the code, directly. But this is not so important...

Comment: I need to determinate each time wich file to open. As the date will ervery time be in 2 files, as they are exported, their name will change (date on name file), so I want to make it easier for the user. Let him choose the file and important its data.

Comment: OK. I only tried to emphasize that it is not faster. Use them if no other choices... I am leaving now.

Comment: `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],wbEmployees.worksheets(1).columns("A1:G"&cpt),6)"` will not be the string you are expecting so the issue is likely that you have not built this properly. You can use Debug.Print to easily check strings are correct. The use of `"` within an assignment needs to be escaped `" => ""` otherwise you can build strings normally so something like `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-3],'" & wbEmployees.Name & "'" & wbEmployees.worksheets(1).Name & "!A1:G" & cpt & "),6)"`

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code. Not tested, but this is the idea for a fast solution. It avoids clipboard, uses only arrays and drops the arrays content at once:

```
Public Sub getData__()
    Dim wsK As Worksheet, wsMP As Worksheet, pathKeys As String, pathEmployees As String, arr, arrCols
    pathKeys = openKeys
    pathEmployees = openEmployees
    'setting the workbook to make the code more compact and easy to be read
    Set wsMP = Workbooks("Macro_PORTAL_APRR.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
    If pathKeys <> "" Then
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'no need of optimization...
        Dim wbKeys As Workbook
        Set wbKeys = GetObject(pathKeys)
        Set wsK = wbKeys.Worksheets(1) 'set the necessary sheet to easily use it in the next part
        
        arr = Intersect(wsK.UsedRange, wsK.Range("A:G")).Value 'Place the used range in an array
         arrCols = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), Array(1, 2))  'extract the first two columns from the main array
        wsMP.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(arrCols), UBound(arrCols, 2)).Value = arrCols 'drop the content in B:C columns
        
        arrCols = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), Array(3))
        wsMP.Range("Q1").Resize(UBound(arrCols), UBound(arrCols, 2)).Value = arrCols
        
        arrCols = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), Array(4))
        wsMP.Range("S1").Resize(UBound(arrCols), UBound(arrCols, 2)).Value = arrCols
        
        arrCols = Application.Index(arr, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arr) & ")"), Array(5, 6, 7))
        wsMP.Range("Y1").Resize(UBound(arrCols), UBound(arrCols, 2)).Value = arrCols
              
    End If
    
    If pathEmployees <> "" Then
        Dim wbEmployees As Workbook, wsE As Worksheet, rng As Range, rngLV As Range, arrV
        Set wbEmployees = GetObject(pathKeys)
        Set wsE = wbEmployees.Worksheets(1)
        Set rng = wsMP.Range("E1:E" & wsMP.Range("H" & wsMP.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row) 'set the range containing the lookup values
        Set rngLV = wsE.Range("A1:G" & wsE.Range("H" & wsE.rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)  'set the range containing the lookup area
        'place all range vllookup in an array
        arrV = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, rngLV, 6, False)
          wsMP.Range("H1").Resize(UBound(arrV), UBound(arrV, 2)).Value = arrV   'drop the array content, at once
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @LyessD Please, test the updated code. It was a mistake in the used range to obtain `arrV`... And let us discuss here.

Comment: @LyessD Now, I must leave my office. If something to be clarified, I will be available after some hours...

Comment: Yes, I am testing your code :) As soon I'm done testing it, I get back to you ;)

Comment: @LyessD please, insert the testing line I recommended above. If the ranges in discussion addresses are returned correctly, the vlookup array should be created in less than a second. First range should be the one where the vlookup values exist, and the second one the range where to search for.

Comment: is it how the testing line should look like : `Set rngLV = wsE.Range("A1:G" & wsE.Range("H" & wsE.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row): Debug.Print rng.Address, rngLV.Address: Stop` ?

Comment: Yes. Try it! Nothing wrong can happen...

Comment: I tried the above code. It does things but not really what I expect haha (concerning data from `wbKeys`). Anyway it is not what I'm struggling with. The code stops at the debug line, when I press F5 an error occur : `Error 1004 : Impossible to read VLookup property of WorksheeFunction class`.

Comment: It is a mistake in the Wookup call. I will adapt it in less than an hour. Basically,  rng must be built for the E:E column, not for H:H...

Comment: @LyessD Please, test the updated code. Try refreshing the page (this one) before copying the code...

Comment: Still the same result ^^ I am looking for an work around of your solution and mine. I'll let you know if i find something.

Comment: @LyessD Not necessarily, I think. What about the suggested `Debug.Print` code line? What does it return in `Immediate Window`? I maybe did not understand which to be the involved ranges... If you want placing Vlookup formulas instead of creating an array, I can adapt the code, or provide another variant, but I like to understand that the necessary ranges are the ones I assumed they should be... If not something confidential and you have AnyDesk (or you want installing it, it is free), i can connect to your computer and see what's going wrong...